# Is there any possiblity to exit socket.receive() if it is empty

Tags: python, c#, sockets, client, task

I am running my server using python like this:
[Running multiple sockets using asyncio in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571622/running-multiple-sockets-using-asyncio-in-python)

c# client code:

Task class for calling server multiple times which run continously:

```
SocketConnector socketConnector = new SocketConnector();

while (true) {
        socketConnector.establishConnection(60001);
        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doLogic(1, socketConnector));
        socketConnector.establishConnection(60002);
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doLogic(2, socketConnector));
        socketConnector.establishConnection(60003);
        Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doLogic(3, socketConnector));
        socketConnector.establishConnection(60004);
        Task task4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doLogic(4, socketConnector));
        socketConnector.establishConnection(60005);
        Task task5 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doLogic(5, socketConnector));
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3,task4, task5);
}

void doLogic(int batchIdentifier,SocketConnector socketConnector)
{      
        GC.Collect();
        z = socketConnector.ServerRequest(batchIdentifier);
        ///process data 
}
```

**SocketConnector class**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class SocketConnector
{
public string ip = "127.0.0.1";
public int port = 60000;
private Socket client;
[SerializeField]
private int dataOut;
private byte[] dataIn; //debugging

public SocketConnector()
{
}

public void establishConnection(int port)
{
    client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    client.Connect(ip, port);
    if (!client.Connected)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Connection Failed");
    }
}

public byte[] ServerRequest(int dataOut)
{

    this.dataOut = dataOut; //debugging
    this.dataIn = SendAndReceive(dataOut); //debugging
    return this.dataIn;
}

private byte[] SendAndReceive(int dataOut)
{
    
    byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(dataOut);
    client.Send(intBytes);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1500];
    Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);


    byte[] z = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1500];
    int lenght = 1, byteIndex = 0;
    while( (lenght = client.Receive(bytes)) != 0) // blocking point
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, z, byteIndex, lenght);
        byteIndex += lenght;
    } 

    Array.Resize(ref z, byteIndex);
    return z;
}

}
}
```

The problem that i think cause infinite loop/ block is the fact that every socket  is running forever on server side  so when i go for a second time to do client.Receive() and it finds nothing will just remain in an infinite waiting state. I need to use while for client.Receive() cos i saw that sometimes it is needed to come back in client.Receive to not lose some parts of the bytes send from server.  Do you have any idea how i can tell to the receiver to  move on if  it is noting in receive without killing connection from server side.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you receive binary data you have to proceed with a byte count unless you can use a byte that is not in the data as a terminating character.

Comment: Can you provide a short example ?

Comment: You have a Master/Slave Communication System.  You do not want to close the sender (Python) until the Receiver (c#) read all the information.  c# will wait until the sender closes the socket.  So there should be a application layer that does something like following 1) c# request the data 2) python sends data preceded with byte count 3) c# get all the data 4) c# sends message to python that all data was received so python can terminate 5) c# closes connection 6) python wait until connection is clo

Comment: Another hint: there is hardly ever a reason to call `GC.Collect();` Have a  look at [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) - those are automatically dispose everything inside one of these blocks. Usally GC does what it should, without calling it manually.