# Unity3d client - Python server real-time communication

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, parallel-processing

I am trying to create a client server app using Unity3D and python. I am trying to send big amount of data from server to client in real time. In order to do that i divided the data to be received in smaller bulks so the serialization/deserialization to be faster so the update of unity objects based on data to be faster as well.

I approached the problem like this:

I open 5 sockets and each try to handle the request based on an identifier

On client I use parallel.foreach for sending the five identifiers and receiving then in parallel.

The issue is that `client.Receive` blocks when there is no data to receive. I tried to set a timeout but it is not really helpful.

Also the length of data is variable for the packages received.

Python server implementation is similar to this but it is not that relevant i assume tho: [Is it possible to run multiple asyncio in the same time in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703083/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-asyncio-in-the-same-time-in-python)

```
Socket class: 

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.IO;
public class SocketConnector
{
    public string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    public int port = 60000;
    private Socket client;
    [SerializeField]
    private int dataOut;
    private byte[] dataIn; //debugging
    public SocketConnector() { }
    public void establishConnection(int port)
    {
        client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.Connect(ip, port);
    }

    public byte[] ServerRequest(int dataOut)
    {
        //print("request");
        this.dataOut = dataOut; //debugging
        this.dataIn = SendAndReceive(dataOut); //debugging
        return this.dataIn;
    }

    private byte[] SendAndReceive(int dataOut)
    {
        byte[] z = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1500];
        try
        {
            byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(dataOut);
            client.Send(intBytes);
            client.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;

            //allocate and receive bytes
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1500];
            Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            int lenght = 1, byteIndex = 0;
        
            lenght = client.Receive(bytes); // is blocking here cos no data is received sometime  
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, z, byteIndex, lenght);
            byteIndex += lenght;

            Array.Resize(ref z, byteIndex);
            Debug.Log("request received");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("smth happened");
        }

        client.Close();
        return z;
    }
}

Main class:  

...
 void Start()
  {
    ThreadCompoennt threadComponent = new ThreadComponent(socketConnector, this, featureMapCreator);
    threadComponent.init();
  }
...


Thread component:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using MessagePack;
using System;

public class ThreadComponent
{

Thread thread;
SocketConnector socketConnector;
Main main;
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ushort[][]>> feature;
StructHelper structHelper;
byte[] z;

public ThreadComponent(SocketConnector socketConnector, Main main, FeatureMapCreator featureMapCreator)
{
    this.featureMapCreator = featureMapCreator;
    this.socketConnector = socketConnector;
    this.main = main;
}

public void init()
{
    thread = new System.Threading.Thread(doLogic);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
void doLogic()
{
    List<int> integerList = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); 

        Parallel.ForEach(integerList, i =>
        {
            socketConnector.establishConnection(60000 + i);
            doLogicGetData(i, socketConnector);
        });
    }    
}


void doLogicGetData(int batchIdentifier, SocketConnector socketConnector)
{
    z = socketConnector.ServerRequest(batchIdentifier);
    if (z.Length != 0)
    {
        this.feature = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,ushort[][]>>>(z);
        ..... do update based on batch identifier
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Socket.ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: I did but i did not manage to implement it, do you have a suggestion for my current implementation how to modify using Socket.ReceiveAsync ?

Comment: The issue in your code is the logic itself. You're using a Stream TCP Socket, but in your implementation you use it like an HTTP connection (i.e with requests).

Here's an example of asynchronous Socket communication : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-an-asynchronous-client-socket

It's a bit outdated since it doesn't use async/await but understanding the logic is what matters.

Comment: Can you provide an example because i was not able to implement it ?

Comment: What have you tried ? if you need an example, you can search for one on the internet, which will probably be better than the one I'll do.